# Git removes first character from branch name

Tags: git, gogs

I have a problem with using git. I created a new repository "test". Then I created the branch "master", put some files in there, committed and pushed it. Everything works fine. Now I create a new branch with

```
git branch release_test
git checkout release_test
git commit -m "new release"
git push
```

And two new branches are created. One that is called "release_test", and another one that is called "elease_test". I am 100% sure that there are no spelling mistakes or something like that. I tried this twice with completely new repositories. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: New branches are created using git checkout -b <branch-name>. Are you using the -b ?

Comment: No, since I create the branch beforehand with "git branch <branch-name>". As far as I know, there is no difference between those two methods, despite using -b is probably more elegant.

Comment: @DanteAdams Branches can also be created with `git branch <name>` like OP did here. `git checkout -b <name>` is just a shortcut to do that then check it out.

Comment: Do you have a reproducer that others can try? My own guess (but it's just a guess) is that you, or the receiving Git, have set up a Git hook script that has a bug in it, but without a reproducer (a [mre]) guessing is about all we can do.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the hint. I'll check out if I can find any Git hook scripts. Also I'll try to provide a reproducer in the upcoming days.